# ZF2: Rendering HTML-Tags in navigation menu (turning off HTML-escaper)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

**The problem:**

If you want to place HTML markup within your Zend Framework 2 navigation, e.g. like this:

```php
<?php
'navigation' => array(
 default' => array(
         array(
             'label' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home',
             'route' => 'home',
         ),
...
```

and we want to display it with the view helper

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu())?>
```

...ZF will automatically escape all HTML markup. The result will be:

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home (No HTML markup was rendered.)
```

**So how can we render HTML markup in menu labels?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to answer this question myself since I couldn't find an answer anywhere else and it might be helpful to you.

The solution is really simple. The view helper `$this->navigation('navigation')->menu()` has a method that does exactly this! The method is called `->escapeLabels()`. Simply add it and you're done:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->escapeLabels(false)?>
```

**Warning:** Of course, as always be careful when rendering unescaped text from a source you can't trust (e.g user input).